# Issue refresh listview in tab fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have location based application with 2 fragments tabs : Map and Places.

The Map tab is a `MapFragment` and the Places fragment should contains the list of all visited places.

A service is running in background to get the Longitude and Latitude and put it a `SQLITE` database.
In the Places `fragment`, I have a `button` and a `listview` that displays the top 50 places inserted in the `SQLITE` when I click the first time on the button, but the listview is not refreshed when a click on the button the next time. It seems like the listview remains static.

Do you please have any idea, or how should I refresh the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue my following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329970/android-listview-adapter-wont-refresh). It was due to my CustomAdapter implementation.